# How to remove an unneccessary space within a link

Tags: html, email

I'm having trouble trying to remove a space that has been added to a hyper link.  The HTML code for the link is correct and I even tested it within my browser.  It works fine, however when I past the code into my email service provider and do a test send the links still come in with an unnecessary space.

I'm stumped as to what to do.

Comment: This is a too much generic question. Please, try to add some details. Thank you.

Comment: Please read the FAQ to see tips on improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough information - http://stackoverflow.com/faq Pasting the link here is a good start :)

Comment: Not a lot to go on, perhaps list your code and/or state your e-mail client.

Comment: Little details like what language and platform you are using, what the data you have is and what you want it to be, what you have tried and where you are stuck would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(url), nd on the other end  HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(url)

Comment: There is no indication in this post that the OP is using .NET at all. Don't make assumptions. It is better to wait for more details from the OP than give a completely unhelpful answer. Even if the OP _were_ using .NET, your answer wouldn't help.

Comment: In fact, there isn't even any indication the OP is using _any_ programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the anchor is on one line. Your email service provider may be breaking it out to something like:

```
<a href="">
    text
</a>
```

Which could cause extra spaces to show up.